# 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python

I have hundred of rows of Data like this:

```
Patch: 148077-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 120011-14 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr
Patch: 148407-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 144500-19 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr, SUNWcsu
Patch: 148683-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 120011-14 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr
Patch: 148948-01 Obsoletes:  Requires: 118833-36, 127127-11 Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr
Patch: 121061-01 Obsoletes:  Requires:  Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr
Patch: 150435-01 Obsoletes:  Requires:  Incompatibles:  Packages: SUNWcsr
Patch: 149171-02 Obsoletes: 148407-01 Requires: 118833-36, 137137-09, 144500-19
```

I want to get a comma separated string of values which are after string "Patch:" i.e. "148077-01,148407-01,148683-01..."

I have written a code, however I am getting error "'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"

Below is my code, please help:

```
def getPatchId(self):
    PatchId = None

    output = None
    finalOutput = []
    output = self.client.execCmd('showrev -p | grep SUNWcsr')

    if output:
        for line in output.split('\n'):
            outString = re.match(r".*?Patch:\:\s+([^\s]+)", line)

        finalOutput.append('outString')

        return finalOutput
```

Comment: There is no call to `strip()` in the code you posted.

Comment: I think he meant `split` ?

Comment: Is `output` a multiline-string or a list of single-line strings?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- The regular expression is wrong (colon specified twice, for example)
- `PatchId` initialized to `None`, but never used
- `output` needlessly initialized to `None`
- `finalOutput` is not really a string, it is an object and it could be `None`
- You were appending the string literal `'outString'` to the final output and that appending happens outside of the for loop

With that in mind, here is the code which I fixed those issues. Note how the patch ID is extracted from `matched`, the result of the regular expression matching.

```
def getPatchId(self):
    patch_ids = []
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        matched = re.match(r"Patch:\s+([^\s]+)", line)
        if matched is not None:
            patch_ids.append(matched.groups()[0])

    return patch_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see some errors in your code.

- You're appending the string `'outString'` to your list `finalOutput` instead of the value of `outString`.
- The value returned by `re.match()` is not a string, but a `Match` object. To get the group captured by your regex, you should call `outString.group(1)` (`group(0)` holds the original string).
- Your regex pattern has two colons.
- The indentation for `finalOutput.append()` seems wrong. Your're appending just the value of `outString` as it is in the last iteration of your `for` loop.

I believe your code should look something like the following:

```
def getPatchId():
    output = None
    finalOutput = []
    output = self.client.execCmd('showrev -p | grep SUNWcsr')

    if output:
        for line in output.split('\n'):
            outString = re.match(r".*?Patch\:\s+([^\s]+)", line)

            finalOutput.append(outString.group(1))

        return finalOutput
```

This is not directly responsible to the error your getting, but may be the cause of it somewhere else in your code.